# How to convert decimal to bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, decimal, byte

I need to get the seventh root of a very large number in python3. I tried many things but I got overflowed so I thought I'd use decimal and it seems fine to me but I just can't convert it to bytes so I can convert it to base64 after.

Here is my code (`c` is that large number):

```
from decimal import *
import base64
if len(str(c)) > 25: getcontext().prec = len(str(c))
else:getcontext().prec =25
x = Decimal(str(c))
a = x ** Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
res = a.quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
res = int.to_bytes(res, length=int(res.bit_length()/8+1), byteorder='big', signed=False)
print(base64.b64encode(res).decode("utf-8"))
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-85e144f30dc7> in <module>()
----> 1 res = int.to_bytes(res, length=int(res.bit_length()/8+1), byteorder='big', signed=False)
      2 print(base64.b64encode(res).decode("utf-8"))

AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'bit_length'
```

I know I should get it. but I just copied the way I used to convert int to bytes.

Comment: You could have included the `c` to make the example reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your decimal to a string first then to bytes

```
x = Decimal(str(c))
a = x ** Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
s = str(a)
b = bytes(str(a), encoding = 'utf-8')
res = base64.b64encode(b)
```

To decode:

```
v = base64.b64decode(res)
v.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Why are you using the _utf-8_ encoding? _ascii_ should be enough for representing a number. Also the [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method of the `str` type could be used, i.e. `b = s.encode()`

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the size of a number in bytes by taking its 256-base logarithm (because a byte can encode 256 different numbers):

```
length = math.ceil(math.log(res, 256))
res = int.to_bytes(res, length=length, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

Comment: Isn't that subject to some floating-point error? I could see this being off by one if the number is +/- 1 from a power of 256.

Comment: @MarkRansom +1 - possible, but never -1 (because of `math.ceil`). You want to have _at least_ that many bytes.